# What is the meaning of the concept of "symmetry protected phase"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking

What is the meaning of the concept of "symmetry protected phase"? Why is it called "symmetry protected" and what is the difference with "symmetry unprotected"?

There is a similar question of course but I could not understand it. Please explain to me in a simple way.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what about the other question you couldn't understand, it would help to provide an explanation which makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest explanation I can think of goes as follows. Consider two zero-temperature quantum mechanical Hamiltonians $H_A$ and $H_B$ (acting on the same Hilbert space $\mathscr H$) which have ground states $|\Omega_A\rangle$ and $|\Omega_B\rangle$, respectively.  Furthermore, assume that those ground states are separated from the lowest-energy excited states by nonzero energy gaps $\Delta_A>0$ and $\Delta_B>0$.

Let $\mathscr O$ be the space of linear operators on the Hilbert space $\mathscr H$. A continuous$^\dagger$ function $F:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathscr O$ (so $F(\lambda)$ is an operator on $\mathscr H$ for every value of $\lambda\in[0,1]$) which has the property that $F(0)=H_A$ and $F(1)=H_B$ is called a *continuous deformation* of $H_A$ into $H_B$.  A trivial example of such a function is given by
$$F(\lambda) = (1-\lambda)H_A + \lambda H_B, \qquad F(0)=H_A \quad F(1) = H_B$$

**Q: Is it possible to continuously deform $H_A$ into $H_B$ *without* closing the energy gap?**

Obviously it's possible to continuously deform any two operators in $\mathscr O$ into one another; the example given above suffices. However, it is **not** clear that it is possible to do so while maintaining a non-zero energy gap at all times. If such a deformation exists, then $H_A$ and $H_B$ correspond to the same topological phase. If *no* such deformation exists - which means that any continuous deformation of $H_A$ into $H_B$ necessarily closes the gap at least once - then they correspond to distinct topological phases.

---

As it turns out, the existence of topological order defined above is not a given, insofar as it does not exist in 1D; any 1D Hamiltonian can be deformed into every other 1D Hamiltonian without closing the gap. However, there is a weaker notion that is still of great practical interest, and that is the notion of *symmetry-protected* topological phases.

The idea is the same, but we're simply adding another constraint. Let's say $H_A$ and $H_B$ both satisfy a particular symmetry constraint (say, time-reversal symmetry). We can ask if its possible to continuously deform $H_A$ into $H_B$ without closing the gap *and without breaking the symmetry*.  If this is not possible, then $H_A$ and $H_B$ correspond to different *symmetry-protected* topological phases.

Essentially, if you imagine the space of all possible Hamiltonians, then at least in 1D you can always find a continuous path from one to the other which doesn't close the energy gap. However, if you impose a particular symmetry requirement, then the set of Hamiltonians which satisfy that requirement constitute "islands" inside the space of all Hamiltonians, and it is not possible to get from one island to another without either closing the gap or breaking the symmetry.

Comment: Do you have a review/reference for the statement that you can always deform in 1D/3D without closing the gap (with no symmetry requirements)?

Comment: @QCD_IS_GOOD Whoops - mental typo there. Intrinsic topological order does not exist in 1D, but it does exist in 3D. The paper classifying topological phases in 1D is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3745), and in 3D [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04221) (and subsequent papers).